# Using Post and requests to login to web-scrape data with python

Tags: python, html, python-requests

I'm an accountant trying to broaden my horizons; I'm fairly new to python and wanted to automate logging-in to a website and extracting data that can't be downloaded. I need help with the login. I'm not sure if my dictionary keys for the payload are right because I'm honest to god terrible with html. I also don't think the website checks for bots and needs a header but I could be wrong. Here is my code so far:

````
payload = {'login:username': '*****','login:password': '*********','login:j_id28': 'Login'}
with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://fms.flexepos.com/FlexeposWeb/login.seam'
    r = s.post(url, data=payload)
    s = s.get('the website I want to get the data from')
    print(s.text)```

#Thanks geese
````

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your code should look like following:

```
payload = {
    'login': 'username',
    'password': '*********',
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://fms.flexepos.com/FlexeposWeb/login.seam'
    r = s.post(url, data=payload)
    s = s.get('the website I want to get the data from')
    print(s.text)

# Thanks geese
```

But if you will still have troubles with that, you can [use this tool](https://curl.trillworks.com/). It allows to convert cURL to working Python code. The only thing you need to do for that - open Developer Tools in your browser, login and copy-paste your request there. Tool will convert that request automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You have to scrape `javax.faces.ViewState` from the login page and add it to your payload.
Add headers in your session.

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs

# Create session.
session = requests.Session()

headers = {
    'Host': 'fms.flexepos.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Origin': 'https://fms.flexepos.com',
    'Referer': 'https://fms.flexepos.com/FlexeposWeb/login.seam',
}

# Add headers in session.
session.headers.update(headers)

# Login page request.
login_page_url = 'https://fms.flexepos.com/FlexeposWeb/login.seam'
response = session.get(login_page_url)

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

# Extract javax.faces.ViewState, login:j_id28, login from login page.
token = soup.find('input', {'id': 'javax.faces.ViewState'}).get('value')
j_id28 = soup.find('input', {'name': 'login:j_id28'}).get('value')
login = soup.find('input', {'name': 'login'}).get('value')

jsessionid = response.cookies.get('JSESSIONID')

# Add javax.faces.ViewState, login:j_id28, login in payload.
payload = {
    'login': login,
    'login:username': 'YOUR USERNAME',
    'login:password': 'YOUR PASSWORD',
    'login:j_id28': j_id28,
    'javax.faces.ViewState': token
}

# Request for login.
login_url = 'https://fms.flexepos.com/FlexeposWeb/login.seam;jsessionid={0}'.format(jsessionid)
login_response = session.post(login_url, data=payload, headers=headers)

response = session.get('the website I want to get the data from')
print(response.text)
```